# Windows Phone 7 emulator/performance question

Tags: performance, optimization, mobile, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm waiting to get my phone unlocked by Microsoft so I can try my game on it. I have no idea how the compatibility or performance is.

So I'm just wondering about all that. How well does the emulator actually emulate the phone? If my game is running fine on the emulator without performance issues or graphical abnormalities and all I'm doing is rendering sprites on screen is it safe to assume it will work the same on the phone?

I'm actually very worried about performance and memory. I have a particle system I've made which is very simple, it just involves drawing sprites on screen with varying levels of alpha, but that means I'm rendering tens of sprites, possibly hundreds, at the same time on screen.

Comment: Good question, especially for people working with XNA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue I have found is that while the emulator does emulate the hardware it does not specify maximum requirements. What this means is your game may play well on a high end machine running the emulator it could stutter on the phone.

There isn't a lot you can do about this apart from wait for your phone to unlock and then test it. As a rule always try to optimise your performance as much as you can even if you feel you meet the minimum requirements.

One more note is if you go to geotrust's website there is a chatbox where you can have your application rushed through. I chatted to them the day I sent the verification email with my ID and it was verified 6 hours later.

Comment: I did end up going to geotrust chat support a week after signing up on the app hub. They told me they had already sent an email asking for photo id (they actually hadn't) but would send it again. Upon receiving the email I photcopied my drivers license and sent it back. Then a couple of days later I got an email from Microsoft saying that geotrust said they never got the email. I sent my ID in AGAIN and just yesterday morning Geotrust FINALLY said that they had received my photo ID and it had 'been expedited for final review' I think I'm getting this crap treatment because I live in Australia.

Comment: It could be. I found when doing this sort of thing I sit on chat at every step of the way. So when I pay. When I send the email and finally when I get the confirmation (or if I don't). Since I live in Ireland I find that it is the only way to insure I am not left behind. My total wait time from paying? 2 Working days.

Answer (score 6):

The best thing you can do is test on device if you have performance concerns.

The emulator just runs a VM of the phone OS, utilising all available hardware. If you have a high spec machine, chances are your app could be humming along and on a device it might not.

Short of testing on a device the only thing I could suggest is keeping an eye out for performance do's and don'ts that might be posted around the place.

Answer (score 2):

In most of the cases, if an application runs well inside an emulator, then **most likely** it will work fine on the physical device.

The emulator is designed in a way so that even on powerful machines it tries to limit the performance to that of the phone. Of course, there are no absolute guarantees that the app will run flawlessly on the phone, but I wouldn't worry about that too much if I have a physical device to test on.

Generally, from what I see, in most cases there are no problems with the emulator/phone differences. There are some cases when graphics aren't displayed as needed on the phone and there might be some UI lags, but at the same time those work fine in the emulator. Once again, I wouldn't be concerned about this if there is a phone available.

Comment: As it was said there - the emulator is a virtual machine tuned to be really close performance-wise to the phone itself.

Comment: "There is no correlation at all between performance in the emulator and performance on a device.  It is an emulator of functionality, not performance.  Anyone doing performance testing on the emulator is heading for a world of hurt when they get a device." <- This is the accepted conclusion in that linked thread and others I have been following.

Comment: I wouldn't say that from my experience - mainly because I've seen how apps run in an emulator and on an actual device. If what you're saying is true, then the apps running on the emulator would run way faster than they do. But once again, I am talking from experience.

Comment: They do run faster. The issue lies with what we percieve as fast. Remember most of these devices are running a 1GHZ snap dragon processer so it takes a lot to slow them down. In terms of Silverlight applications there really wont be a difference but XNA performs on a loop and as you start to add in "heavy" methods you will see the drop on the phone but not on the emulator. My suggestion is to get it working on the emulator and optimise on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HTC Trophy, ie- relatively low-end first generation WP7 device.
Even when running the emulator on an i7-930 with 16Gb RAM and Quadro 4000, running a simple tiled background with single animated sprite foreground, the performance when deployed to an actual device is WAY faster and smoother. I initially thought it might have something to do with running normally on the phone vs with debugging, intellitrace etc on the desktop but I think it's a bit of a stretch given how drastic the performance difference is.

If it runs fine on the emulator, you should have no problem with any commerical WP7 device out there... and available hardware will only get faster :)